# Rails form_for params on model undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form_for page that's supposed to save a model called *domain_extension*. However in the controller where I'm trying to save it says

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `domain_extension_params` for DomainExtensionsController:
```

Below are snippets of the code.Have no idea why this doesn't work

**new.html.erb**

```
 <div class="row">
   <%= render 'form', domain_extension: @domain_extension %>
 </div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(domain_extension) do |f|%>
```

**domain_extensions_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @domain_extension = DomainExtension.new       
end

def create
    @domain_extension = DomainExtension.new(domain_extension_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @domain_extension.save
        format.html { redirect_to @domain_extension, notice: 'Domain created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @domain_extension }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @domain_extension.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Does your controller have the method `domain_extension_params`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are missing the `domain_extension_params` method, which is generally a private method, in your `domain_extension_controller.rb` which would contain the whitelisted params.

```rb
private

def domain_extension_params
  params.require(:domain_extension).params(<your params here>)
end
```